# How to treat unmanaged (Unity) exceptions as "crashes" instead of "non-fatals" in Crashlytics

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-fabric

We use Unity 2018.1.6f1 and apparently Crashlytics 2.6.8 (sorry for being so imprecise, I can't find the version number anywhere except of `Plugins/Android/crashlytics/libs/crashlytics-2.6.8.jar` giving an idea).

A Unity game can crash to the home screen (we are talking Android here) when any exception is not handled. As the programmer I'd call this a "crash", and I'd love to see in Fabric's report tools how many people have these crashes to home screen.

However `Fabric.Internal.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsInit.RegisterExceptionHandlers()` sets `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleException;`, which internally calls `Crashlytics.RecordCustomException` which, as per [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/unity/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html), results in

> All custom exceptions will appear as “non-fatal” issues in your iOS and Android Fabric dashboards.

As these unhandled exceptions are in no way "non-fatal" to the apps lifecycle - is there any way to change this to be a proper "crash"?

Tools like Fabric's "Latest Release" tab show how many "crash-free users" there are on a release, but that's only taking "crashes", not "non-fatal issues", into account (which makes sense).

Comment: Same with App Center. I'm looking for a way to treat unhandled exception as crashes, since they are indeed unhandled and leave the app in an undefined state.. Any progress on this?